# How i can have the data in quarters instead of month with Excel VBA Macro

Tags: vba, charts, macros

I had created a Macro with VBA and created a month chart.See the code below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Chart'!$A$1:$L$2")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineStacked
Dim cht As Chart
Dim ser As Series
Set cht = ActiveChart
Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
cht.Parent.Width = 227
cht.Parent.Height = 200
ser.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
ser.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
ser.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(26, 46, 74)
ser.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(26, 46, 74)
With Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects(1).Chart
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = Sheets("Chart").Range("B10")
.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 12
.ChartTitle.Font.Color = RGB(26, 46, 74)
End With
With cht.PlotArea.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(239, 239, 239)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
   End With
 With cht.ChartArea.Fill
.Visible = True
.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 15
.BackColor.SchemeColor = 15
.TwoColorGradient Style:=msoGradientHorizontal, Variant:=1
End With
Dim co As ChartObject
For Each co In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
co.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
co.Chart.PlotArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
Next
Dim Srs As Series
Set Srs = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
Srs.Name = ""
Dim ChartObj As Object
For Each ChartObj In Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects
ChartObj.Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, "Factsheet"
With ActiveSheet
.ChartObjects(1).Top = .Range("D8").Top
.ChartObjects(1).Left = .Range("D8").Left
End With
Next ChartObj
End Sub
```

How i can create the chart with a quarter data in the place of displaying months it will display Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4.

Is that possible to create with VBA?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach to summarize data into quarters is inserting a pivot table and use "group" feature by right clicking into any date value.

**Edit 1**
In response to @Anahit DEV comment. It is very hard to write any code without a source to work with. However, the next macro would help you to achive your goal. Please notice that I wrote some comments for you, and you must to replace these values where required.

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
'PURPOSE: Creates a brand new Pivot table on a new worksheet from data in the ActiveSheet
'Source: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com
'Modified by Dani Aya on 25/03/2016

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String
Dim celda As Range
Dim adrs_date_cell As String
Dim adrs_src_table As String 'address of source table

'you must select the worksheet where the data source table is and then run this macro
adrs_src_table = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Address '<--- assuming second cell in the table is A2

'Determine the data range you want to pivot

  SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range(adrs_src_table).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create a new worksheet
  Set sht = Sheets.Add
  sht.Name = "PT2"

'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
  StartPvt = "PT2!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="QuartersPivotTable1")


'turn on dates in pivot table. Next segment of code insert two row labels (it's means two name columns) and one count value

    'inserting firs row label from the pivot field lists
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuartersPivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "date") '<----- place here a valid field date name from your table
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    'inserting one count value from the pivot field list
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuartersPivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("QuartersPivotTable1")
        .PivotFields ("any_field"), "#", xlCount '<----- Place your field to count rows from table instead if "any_field"
    'inserting second row label from the pivot field list
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuartersPivotTable1").PivotFields("another_field") '<----- place here another field name from your table.
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With


'group your dates by quarters
    '1. Search any date value
    For Each celda In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1048576")
        If IsDate(celda.Value) Then
            'get address where a date value were found
            adrs_date_cell = celda.Address
            Exit For
        End If
    Next celda
    '2. Group by quarters selecting a valid date
    ActiveSheet.Range(adrs_date_cell).Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
        False, True, False, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: But i need to do that automatically with a VBA code not manually @Dani Aya

Comment: you could create pivot table from vba code. See next link: [link](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables)

Comment: So how my code will look like? Could you help me please @Dani Aya?